# How to use twitteroauth to tweet when a wordpress post is published?

Tags: php, wordpress, twitter, oauth

I am trying to tweet when a post is published. before that I implemented https://github.com/abraham/twitteroauth in a front end page where a form can be submitted.

It is tweeting when the form is submitted. works fine.

All the `twitteroauth` files are in my `child-theme` folder.

Now I want to tweet when a post is submitted from the admin panel.

so I tried following code:

```
<?php 
/* Tweet when the post is published */

add_action('future_to_publish', 'send_emails_on_new_event');
add_action('new_to_publish', 'send_emails_on_new_event');
add_action('draft_to_publish' ,'send_emails_on_new_event');
add_action('auto-draft_to_publish' ,'send_emails_on_new_event');
function send_emails_on_new_event($post)
{
    require "autoload.php";
    use Abraham\TwitterOAuth\TwitterOAuth;

    $consumerKey = "My Consumer Key"; // Consumer Key
    $consumerSecret = "My Consumer Secret"; // Consumer Secret
    $accessToken = "My Access Token"; // Access Token
    $accessTokenSecret = "My Access Token Secret"; // Access Token Secret
    $connection = new TwitterOAuth($consumerKey, $consumerSecret, $accessToken, $accessTokenSecret);    

    /* Media - 2 photos */
    $media1 = $connection->upload('media/upload', array('media' => 'https://pbs.twimg.com/media/CTBv1rCVAAEwKjS.jpg'));
    $media2 = $connection->upload('media/upload', array('media' => 'https://pbs.twimg.com/media/CTBv1rCVAAEwKjS.jpg'));
    $parameters = array(
        'status' => 'Tweeted by the post is published',
        'media_ids' => implode(',', array($media1->media_id_string, $media2->media_id_string)),
    );
    $result = $connection->post('statuses/update', $parameters);

    if ($connection->getLastHttpCode() == 200) {
        echo 'Tweeted successfully';
    } else {
        echo 'Something went wrong';
    }
}
?>
```

and I put this code in my `functions.php` but when I go to the admin panel I am getting following message.

[image: admin]

so the error happens because of `use`

I experienced the same kind of error when I tried on my previous front end page also. I fixed it by moving followoing two lines of of code to right after the `get_header();`

```
require "autoload.php";
use Abraham\TwitterOAuth\TwitterOAuth;
```

[image: frontend]

I think I have to do something else when I use `use`. what is that?
How can I fix this?

Comment: Hey i know it is too late but have you got the answer?